# Add different event listener to a set of elements in a loop

Tags: javascript

Hello people of the internet,
I have a set of buttons and if a button is clicked it's content should be appended to a text field's content.

Lets say I have three buttons: [first] [second] [third]
My addEventListener-implementation results in "third" appended to the in text field's content, regardless which button I press. I don't know hot to fix this.

```
function setupListeners() {
    var targetInputField = d.querySelector("#expression");
    var t = d.querySelectorAll(".expression-button").length;
    for (var i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
        var btnElem = d.querySelector("#expression-button-"+i);
        btnElem.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (targetInputField.value == "") {
                targetInputField.value = btnElemLocal.innerText;
            }
            else {
                targetInputField.value += ";"+btnElemLocal.innerText;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**What I want:**

If I click all of the three buttons in a row, the text field's content should be :

> "first;second;third"

And not :

> "third;third;third"

Answer (score 0):

Put the click event code inside another function (`btnClick` in my example) and just call it when you attach the event in `.addEventListener()` inside the loop, then use `this` to refer to the current clicked element :

```
function btnClick() {
  var targetInputField = d.querySelector("#expression");

  if (targetInputField.value == "") {
    targetInputField.value = this.innerText;
  }
  else {
    targetInputField.value += ";"+this.innerText;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var d = document;

function setupListeners() {      
  var t = d.querySelectorAll(".expression-button").length;

  for (var i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
    var btnElem = d.querySelector("#expression-button-"+i);
    
    btnElem.addEventListener('click', btnClick);
  }
}

function btnClick() {
  var targetInputField = d.querySelector("#expression");
  
  if (targetInputField.value == "") {
    targetInputField.value = this.innerText;
  }
  else {
    targetInputField.value += ";"+this.innerText;
  }
}

setupListeners();
```

```html
<button class='expression-button' id='expression-button-1'>First</button>
<button class='expression-button' id='expression-button-2'>Second</button>
<button class='expression-button' id='expression-button-3'>Third</button>

<input id='expression' />
```